# Sending message from Amazon SQS to SQL Database on the basis of message attributes

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

**Use-Case of my task:** For now the use case is that i am filling the details like First Name, Last name etc. in a form and then on click of Submit button, the data goes directly into **Amazon SQS** and then there is a listener defined which contains a button and on that button click the data goes from listener to MSSQL database.

**Scenario(currently):** For now all the message belonging even to the different message attributes are being sent.

**Requirement:** I want to send specific message belonging to a particular message attributes. **For example:** Suppose Class A, Class B and Class C are three different message attributes and Class A contains one message, class B contains two messages and Class C contains four messages, what i want is only the messages of the Class B attribute should be send, not of Class A and Class C.

I want to know that is it possible to send only selected/specific message on the basis of the **Message Attribute** from Amazon SQS to the SQL db ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQS messages cannot be selectively delivered based on message attributes.  Standard practice is for each class of consumer to have its own queue, such that filtering would not be required, because the assumption is that all consumers of a given queue are able to process all messages in the queue.

If you do need a common source of messages to have its output filtered by message attributes, then the suggested solution is to publish messages to an SNS topic, then subscribe queues to that topic based on message attribute filters, which **are** supported in SNS.  This configuration would allow, for example, Queue 1 to capture messages of types A, B, and C, while simultaneously allowing Queue 2 to capture messages of types C, D, and E.  Note the overlap on type C.  This class of messages would be delivered to both queues, in this configuration.

See [Filtering Messages with Amazon SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering.html) and [Send Fanout Event Notifications](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/send-fanout-event-notifications/).

SNS Topics and SQS Queues can be many-to-many mapped, where multiple queues subscribe to multiple topics, in any desired configuration.

Note that when an SQS queue subscribes to an SNS topic, the default behavior is for only the payload to be sent to the queue.  To receive the entire SNS wrapper, including SNS message attributes, enable "raw message delivery" on each subscription.

This leaves the question, then, of what the purpose of SQS message attributes must be, if not for service-side filtering.  They can be metadata for the benefit of the recipient, giving information about the payload without the need to actually deserialize the payload, or they can provide information about the transfer encoding of the payload, such as whether or not the payload had gzip compression and base64 encoding applied by the sender, which the consumer needs to know in order to unpack the payload.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Helped me understand the actual difference between SQS and SNS. So the message based filtering and all the other functionalities like automatically triggering or sending the data from SNS topic to an MSSQL database can be achieved by using the AWS Lambda function along with the SNS. Correct me if i am wrong ? Thanks in advance for your valuable time.

Comment: @Sandy, I'm happy to help.  If you write an event to SNS, you can send it to any number of destinations in parallel, including Lambda functions and SQS queues.  AWS has also announced plans to roll out the ability to use Lambda functions as consumers of an SQS queue, which will also be useful for things like this... your DB updates could be implemented inside the Lambda function, that processes events in a queue... but there is no timetable so far.